# Microsoft.Owin.Hosting not supported in .NET standard 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, owin, .net-standard-2.0

Thanks for giving your time for reading this.I have created a console application in .NET standard 2.0 with NuGet packages below

[image: NuGet packages]

And I have added Program.cs file

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";

            // Start OWIN host 
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Startup.cs

```
using Owin; using System.Web.Http;

namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    class Startup
    {

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    } }
```

When am running the application am getting error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Hosting, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at ClassLibrary1.Program.Main()
```

As per my understanding 'Mirosoft.Owin' is not supported by .NET standard, is there any alternative for this? Thanks in advance for your help.